# MacOS Sierra PHP installation with Homebrew not able to use homebrew php

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, macos-sierra

I recently got my hands on a new macbook and I'm loving the terminal!
I'm now configuring my enviroment to run completely on homebrew and on different php versions. To do this, I am following this guide: https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions

Everything works up to the point of

`brew unlink php@7.2 && brew link --force --overwrite php@5.6`

When I do this I get no error message and everything is OK, however, the guide says that I have to check with php -v to see which version is running and it is NOT php 5.6...

```
PHP 7.1.16 (cli) (built: Apr  1 2018 13:14:42) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Is the message I get back.

When I run `which php`:

```
/usr/local/bin/php
```

What I have tried

Restarting apache

removing everything regarding php from /usr/local/php-*

checking brew, both php 5.6 and apache are running

Could anyone help me? Thank you for your time!

**EDIT (FIXED):
Restarted my Mac and then the brew PHP installation went trough ^^**

Answer (score 1):

You just need to open new shell tab / window. You don't have to restart macOS :)